# Undetectable memory leak

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have a `Stock` class which loads lots of stock data history from a file (about 100 MB). I have a `Pair` class that takes two `Stock` objects and calculates some statistical relations between the two then writes the results to file.

In my main method I have a loop going through a list of pairs of stocks (about 500). It creates 2 stock objects and then a pair object out of the two. At this point the pair calculations are written to file and I'm done with the objects. I need to free the memory so I can go on with the next calculation.

I addition to setting the 3 objects to null I have added the following two lines at the end of the loop:

```
GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Stepping over theses two lines just seems to just free up 50 MB out of the 200-300 MB that is allocated per every loop iteration (viewing it from task manager).

The program does about eight or ten pairs before it gives me a system out of memory exception. The memory usage steadily increases until it crashes at about 1.5 GB. (This is an 8 GB machine running Win7 Ultimate)

I don't have much experience with garbage collection. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code since you asked: (note: program has two modes, 1> add mode in which new pairs are added to system. 2> regular mode which updates the pair files realtime based on `filesystemwatcher` events. The stock data is updated by external app called QCollector.)

This is the segment in `MainForm` which runs in Add Mode:

```
foreach (string line in PairList)
{
    string[] tokens = line.Split(',');

    stockA = new Stock(QCollectorPath, tokens[0].ToUpper()); 
    stockB = new Stock(QCollectorPath, tokens[1].ToUpper()); 

    double ratio = double.Parse(tokens[2]);
    Pair p = new Pair(QCollectorPath, stockA, stockB, ratio);

    // at this point the pair is written to file (constructor handles this)        

    // commenting out the following lines of code since they don't fix the problem
    // stockA = null;
    // stockB = null;
    // p = null;

    // refraining from forced collection since that's not the problem
    // GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration);
    // GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    // so far this is the only way i can fix the problem by setting the pair classes
    // references to StockA and StockB to null
    p.Kill();
}
```

I am adding more code as per request: `Stock` and `Pair` are subclasses of `TimeSeries`, which has the common functionality

```
public abstract class TimeSeries {
     protected List<string> data;

     // following create class must be implemented by subclasses (stock, pair, etc...)
     // as each class is created differently, although their data formatting is identical
     protected void List<string> Create();

     // . . . 

     public void LoadFromFile()
     {
          data = new List<string>();

          List<StreamReader> srs = GetAllFiles();

          foreach (StreamReader sr in srs)
          {
               List<string> temp = new List<string>();
               temp = TurnFileIntoListString(sr);
               data = new List<string>(temp.Concat(data));
               sr.Close()
          }
     }

     // uses directory naming scheme (according to data month/year) to find files of a symbol
     protected List<StreamReader> GetAllFiles()...

     public static List<string> TurnFileIntoListString(StreamReader sr)
     {
          List<string> list = new List<string>();
          string line;
          while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
               list.Add(line);
          return list;
     }

     // this is the only mean to access a TimeSeries object's data
     // this is to prevent deadlocks by time consuming methods such as pair's Create

     public string[] GetListCopy()
     {
          lock (data)
          {
               string[] listCopy = new string[data.count];
               data.CopyTo(listCopy);
               return listCopy();
          }
     }
}

public class Stock : TimeSeries
{
     public Stock(string dataFilePath, string symbol, FileSystemWatcher fsw = null)
     {
          DataFilePath = dataFilePath;
          Name = symbol.ToUpper();
          LoadFromFile();
          // to update stock data when external app updates the files
          if (fsw != null) fsw.Changed += FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_Changed);
     }

     protected void List<string> Create()
     {
          // stock files created by external application
     }


     // . . . 
}

public class Pair : TimeSeries {
     public Pair(string dataFilePath, Stock stockA, Stock stockB, double ratio)
     {
          // assign parameters to local members
          // ...         

          if (FileExists())
               LoadFromFile();
          else
             Create();
     }

     protected override List<string> Create()
     {
          // since stock can get updated by fileSystemWatcher's event handler
          // a copy is obtained from the stock object's data 
          string[] listA = StockA.GetListCopy();
          string[] listB = StockB.GetListCopy();
          List<string> listP = new List<string>();

          int i, j;
          i = GetFirstValidBar(listA);
          j = GetFirstValidBar(listB);
          DateTime dtA, dtB;

          dtA = GetDateTime(listA[i]);
          dtB = GetDateTime(listB[j]);

          // this hidden segment adjusts i and j until they are starting at same datetime
          // since stocks can have different amount of data

          while (i < listA.Count() && j < listB.Count)
          {
              double priceA = GetPrice(listA[i]);
              double priceB = GetPrice(listB[j]);
              double priceP = priceA * ratio - priceB;
              listP.Add(String.Format("{0},{1:0.00},{2:0.00},{3:0.00}"
                   , dtA
                   , priceP
                   , priceA
                   , priceB
              );
              if (i < j)
                   i++;
              else if (j < i)
                   j++;
              else
              {
                   i++; 
                   j++;
              }
          }
     }

     public void Kill()
     {
         data = null;
         stockA = null;
         stockB = null;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your memory leak is here:

```
if (fsw != null) fsw.Changed += FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_Changed);
```

The instance of the stock object will be kept in memory as long as the FileSystemWatcher is alive, since it is responding to an event of the FileSystemWatcher.

I think that you want to either implement that event somewhere else, or at some other point in your code add a:

```
if (fsw != null) fsw.Changed -= fsw_Changed;
```

Given the way that the code is written it might be possible that stock object is intended to be called without a FileSystemWatcher in cases where a bulk processing is done.

In the original code that you posted the constructors of the Stock classes were being called with a FileSystemWatcher. You have changed that now. I think you will find that now with a null FileSystemWatcher you can remove your kill and you will not have a leak since you are no longer listening to the fsw.Changed.

Comment: I had set the fsw to null since it wasn't needed for add and thought my kill method was doing the trick. Thanks again for all your help.